# How to read and write from/to a mongodb database on a node server

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mean-stack, mean

I'm currently doing an apprenticeship as a developper (just started). By now i've learned the basics of angular and the next step, so now my colleagues told me to take that to the next level and store data on a mongodb database.

So they showed me how to create a node server and a mongodb database using the mongo compass

I also installed mongoose and express because it seems like everybody uses those

Now i have a server and a database but i dont know how to write to or read from it

This is the node server they gave me:

```js
const express = require('express'),
      bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
      cors = require('cors'),
      mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const DB = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/database';
mongoose.connect(DB).then(
  () => {console.log('Database is connected')},
  err => {console.log('Can not connect to the Database ' + err)}
);

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

const port =  process.env.PORT || 4000;


const server = app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Listening on Port ' + port);
});
```

I would appreciate it if someone could give me a simple example of how to write to / read from the database and tell me what files to create etc or link me a tutorial which is exactly for my case since i couldn't find a tutorial that suits my situation

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_create_db.asp good for basic query

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) and [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/) documentation.

To read on your database, you can use [find or findOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) methods 
Example :

```
db.users.findOne({login: 'admin'}, function(err, user) {
   if (err) thow err;
   if (user) {
      console.log(user); // This is your admin user
   }
});
```

You also can update this user by modifying his properties, and [save](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) like this :

```
db.users.findOne({login: 'admin'}, function(err, user) {
   if (err) thow err;
   if (user) {
      user.login = 'administrator';
      user.password = 'myPassword';
      user.save(function(err) {
          if (err) throw err;
          // User has been updated !
      }); 
   }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

THis is an example of an api I created, hope it helps you:

```
//CORS
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
  );
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
  next();
});

//CRUD

//Creating a new Report
app.post('/api/reports', (req, res, next) => {
  const report = new Report({
    address: req.body.address,
    placeName: req.body.placeName,
    description: req.body.description,
    abuseType: req.body.abuseType,
    dateOfEvent: req.body.dateOfEvent,
    imageName: req.body.imageName,
    lat: req.body.marker.lat,
    long: req.body.marker.long,
    zipcode: req.body.zipcode,
    city: req.body.city,
    state: req.body.state,
    country: req.body.country
  });

  report
    .save()
    .then(createdReport => {
      res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Report added successfully',
        report: {
          ...createdReport._doc
        },
        status: 201
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: 'Creating report failed!',
        error: error
      });
    });
});

//Getting all reports
app.get('/api/reports', (req, res, next) => {
  Report.find()
    .then(docs => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Reports fetched successfully',
        reports: docs,
        status: 200
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(500).json({
        message: 'Fetching post failed!',
        status: 500
      });
    });
});
```

Angular

```
addReport(report: Report): Observable<ReportAPI> {
    return this.http.post<ReportAPI>(this.BASE_URL, report);
  }

  getReportsDB(): Observable<ReportAPI> {
    return this.http.get<ReportAPI>(this.BASE_URL);
  }
```